# How to get from Medan to Ketambe (Indonesia)?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, indonesia

I want to get to [Ketambe (Aceh province, Indonesia](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Ketambe,+Aceh+Tenggara+Regency,+Aceh/@3.6731662,98.0532438,9z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303a0113b364893f:0x370daf54763ab72d)) from [Medan (Indonesia)](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra/@2.8690063,99.1638783,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262)

What transportation options are available (buses, shared taxi, taxi, or else)?

Note that I do not have my own car.

Comment: Hi Adrien, did you go to Ketambe? Any feedback on the best way to get there?

Comment: @stefano No I didn't. Private taxi is usually the best option. Shared taxi are quite good, although they may lose time to go pick up someone on the way. Buses are the "real" backpacker way ;) I'd go for private taxi if I had the money or if with a group of 4 or 5 people.

Comment: thanks Adrien, very helpful. I am going in a couple of weeks, I'd probably go for the shared taxi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Mini Bus

From Medan (Berastagi)
In Padang Bulan (Medan) several bus terminals are located in Jalan Jamin Ginting. 
Bus companies Adi Guna Taksi, Anugrah travels, Bona Taksi, Borneo Taksi (terminal in the front of Citra Garden of Jalan Jamin Ginting) will pick you up at your hotel in Medan and take you to Kutacane 
for 100.000 IDR. The trip takes 8 hours, a mini bus departs each hour between 5 am and 11  pm.
Contact Adi Guna Travel: +62-852-6234-5454
Contact Anugrah Travel: +62-823-6253-6988
Bus company name BTN and Karsima take you to Kutacane for 50.000 IDR. Each hour between 5 am and 11 am.

Buses from Kutacane to Ketambe usually leave from 6 am every hours until 5 pm for 10.000 IDR.

All buses leaving from Medan pass 2 hours later in Berastagi.

From Banda Aceh
There is only one nightbus to Blangkejeren (Ketambe), leaving from Jalan Tgk. Imum Lueng Bata Terminal. The trip takes about 12 hours and costs 150.000 IDR.

By Private Car

One way transfer to Ketambe
From Medan: 750 000 IDR (1 500 000 IDR round trip)
From Berastagi: 650 000 IDR (1300 000 IDR round trip)
From Banda Aceh: 1 700 000 IDR (3 400 000 IDR round trip)
From Lake Toba: 1 100 000 IDR (2 200 000 round trip)

By Air

The fastest way is to fly from Medan or Banda Aceh to Kutacane with a small airplane run by companies NBA and Susi Air. NBA (Nusantara Buana Air) flies twice a week on Wednesday and Sunday for 150.000 IDR. The more modern Susi Air has a plane flying daily and costs 415.000 IDR.

Airline NBA
Tickets can only be booked in one of the offices. Staff normally don't speak English. Offices are closed on Sundays.  Contact Details:
Medan: 
Jln. Brig. General Katamso 100 / +62 61-4534680
Banda Aceh: 
Jln. Tengku Nyak Arif 1 / +62 651-333777
Kutacane:
Jln. Gen. Ahmad Yani 33 / +62 812-6003434

Airline Susi Air
Booking a ticket in advance is difficult, try to make contact by phone or e-mail:
Hotline: +62 (0)811 211 3080 / 3090 
(Medan)
Email: info@susiair.com
Website: www.susiair.com
Medan: Counter at the airport  / +62 (0)61 785 2169
Kutacane: Jln. Gen. Ahmad Yani / +62 (0)813 6034 3497

As I know from guests, there was no any reply on e-mail booking requests. On their webpage you can reserve a flight for 24 hours only. Reserved tickets can not be paid by credit card via internet, but should be paid cash at any of the offices.

Comment: you could have as well cited the source:
http://users.telenet.be/sarahjane/87054575550b2710415065/how-to-get-to-ketambe.html